# environment in ocaml - syntax error on `type a' env`

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, ocaml

I need to declare and use an environment in ocaml. In my study book, I find the following code:

```
type a' env =  (string * 'a)list;;
exception WrongBindList;;
let emptyenv(x) = [("", x)];;
let rec applyenv(x, y) = match x with
        | [(_, e)] -> e
        | (i1, e1) :: x1 -> if y = i1 then e1 
                 else applyenv(x1, y)
        | [] -> failwith("wrong env")   ;;   
let bind(r, l, e) = (l, e) :: r ;;

type evT = Unbound |  FunVal of evFun | RecFunVal of string*evFun
and evFun = string * exp * (evT env);;
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Type exp defined.
#Toplevel input:
>type a' env =  (string * 'a)list;;
>        ^^^
Syntax error.
```

Why am I getting this error? I am keen to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please don't edit your question such that its meaning is altered, and every existing answer rendered meaningless.  This website is intended as a repository of useful questions and answers, not a help desk. If you have a new question, you should post a new question, not edit old ones, so that they can potentially remain useful for others. Though, honestly, you should really be able to figure these out on your own. Please also see [ask].

Comment: Stop editing your post! Your error is that you wrote `a'` and not `'a`. If after correcting it you still have an error, add an horizontal rule and explain the new error you have or create a new question. But stop editing your post.

Answer (score 3):

`type a' env` should be `type 'a env`

`'a`, with the apostrophe before the name, is a type variable. It is also referred to again on the right-hand side of the equal sign. `a'` is just an identifier that is not previously defined, but also apparently not syntactically valid in that position.

Comment: it is the same with 'a instead of a'

Comment: #Toplevel input:
    >type 'a env =  (string * 'a) list ;;
    >               ^
    Syntax error.

Comment: I don't understand the question. They should both be `'a`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the quote before the type variable name rather than after:

```
type 'a env =  (string * 'a) list
```